# User defined const char* literal example from cppreference

Tags: c++, c++11, user-defined-literals

On cppreference there is this example (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal):

```
void operator"" _print ( const char* str )
{
    std::cout << str;
}


int main(){
    0x123ABC_print;
}
```

Output:
    0x123ABC

And I fail to understand what exactly this is doing. First I thought that 0x123ABC would just be seen as a string, but `0x123ABCHello_print` doesn't compile. Then I thought that the `operator<<` is overloaded so that it always prints it in hexadecimal form, but `123_print` prints `123`. Also it's case-sensitive: `0x123abC_print` prints `0x123abC`.

Can someone explain this to me? On one hand it only takes integers as argument but on the other it treats them like string literals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal

`void operator"" _print(const char* str)` shows that your literal is taken as `const char*` and then printed out, it's why it's case-sensitive.

`0x123ABCHello_print` doesn't work because `0x123ABCHello` is not a number, for user-defined string literals you'd need `"0x123ABCHello"_print`

Comment: You also need a second `size_t` argument for the string version of the operator.

Comment: Does that mean I would have to convert it myself to an integer including case sensitivity? Seems so overly complicate and inefficient.

Comment: @MichaelMahn: depends on what you need, of course, but in general, no you don't have to: https://wandbox.org/permlink/gI9nI1ApJUsoCmLy

Answer (score 2):

In [the example code](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) you see:

```
12_w; // calls operator "" _w("12")
```

Which means that an integer literal is converted to a `const char[]`. This is then accepted by your user-defined literal. Since it's a `const char*` ,`operator<<` will just print until it hits `\0`, no special handling as you'd have normally when printing out an integer literal such as `std::cout << 0xBADFOOD;`.